# How to get apache beam for dataflow GCP on Python 3.x

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm very newby with GCP and dataflow. However , I would like to start to test and deploy few flows harnessing dataflow on GCP. According to the documentation and everything around dataflow is imperative use the Apache project BEAM. Therefore and following the official documentation [here](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/) the supported version of python is 2.7

Honestly this is fairly disappointed due to the fact that Python version 2.x will vanish due not official support and everybody is working with version 3.x. Nevertheless, I want to know if someone knows how to get ready beam and GCP dataflow running in python version.

I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ss6SaNBHLGc) and some how this parson complete this wonderful milestone and apparently it runs on Python 3.5.

**Update**:

Guys I want just raise a thought that has crossed my minds since I’m struggling with dataflow. I really feel highly disappointed in the sense how challenging is start hands on with this tool either version Java or Python. From python there are constrains about the version 3 which is pretty much the current standard. In the other hand, java has issues running on version 11 and I have to tweak a bit to run over version 8 my code and then I start to struggle with many incompatibilities on the code. Briefly , if really GCP wants to move forward and become the #1 there is so much much to improve. :disappointed:

**Workaround**:

I downgraded my java version to jdk 8 , install maven and now my eclipse version is working for Apache Beam.

I finally solved but, GCP really please consider enhance and span the support for the most recent versions of Java/Python.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See @VibhorJain 's answer, it is working now.

---

Currently there is **NO** way to use Python3 for apache-beam (you may write an adapter for it, but for sure meaningless).

The support of Python3.X is on going, please take a look on this [apache-beam issue](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1251?subTaskView=unresolved.).

P.S. In the video, Python 3.5.2 is **ONLY** for the editor version, it is not the python running the apache-beam. Please be noticed, in the bash, Python 2.7 is running.

Comment: The only thing I can say about dataflow is a huge sadness and disappointment. I really wanted to deploy few pipelines but I have to face many compatibility constrains before get hands on this is so sadness :(

Comment: @AndresUrregoAngel, you may consider using Cloud Dataproc instead, though I didn't try. Dataproc can establish Spark jobs, and spark can run in Python3.4+, providing you more freedom (and a bit more tedious job like balancing).

Answer (score 13):

You can now run Apache Beam on Python 3.5 (I tried both on Direct as well as DataFlow runner).`apache-beam==2.11.0`

when running it comes with warning:

> UserWarning: Running the Apache Beam SDK on Python 3 is not yet fully supported. You may encounter buggy behavior or missing features.

I already noticed, `beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub()` is broken. Pushing messages to PubSub but the pipeline never reads the messages (trying on Direct Runner).

Hope with time things will improve.

Comment: It seems it's actively being work on (finally!), there are quite a lot active [changes now](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1251?focusedCommentId=16789854&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16789854)

Comment: Thanks @kotrfa for the link. Useful to follow

Comment: Welcome. I tried a basic example with DirectRunner on Python 3.7 and it worked fine.

Comment: oh great! that means updated client libraries now support Py 3.5+

Answer (score 1):

There has been a lot of new happening on [Python 3](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1251?focusedCommentId=16890504&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16890504) support. DataFlow [now supports](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python#set-up-your-environment) that as `beta`!
[image: data flow mentioning 3.7]